# Measuring block I/O delays using proc FS

Tags: performance, io, proc

I'm trying to measure IO delay due disk access. For this I'm using `delayacct_blkio_ticks` from `/proc/[pid]/stat` response. What I'm getting is a constant 0, no matter how much IO is done in my app.

The proc man says:

```
42) delayacct_blkio_ticks  %llu  (since Linux 2.6.18)
Aggregated block I/O delays, measured in clock ticks (centiseconds).
```

I'm using 3.0.101 kernel version.

But... if I use `top`, I get a constant non zero "%wa" value.

```
top - 00:49:36 up 186 days, 15:06,  3 users,  load average: 4.54, 5.80, 5.53
Tasks: 270 total,   1 running, 269 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.0%id,  3.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    387581M total,   261149M used,   126432M free,      295M buffers
Swap:    12266M total,      193M used,    12073M free,    82346M cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S   %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4290 build     20   0  512g 169g  25m S      8 44.9 241:27.65 java
 7614 build     20   0  9056 1268  828 R      0  0.0   0:01.28 top
    1 root      20   0 10540  560  536 S      0  0.0   0:46.33 init
```

Am I reading the wrong data for this measurement? Why does `top` report it correctly?
The WA value is above 0 only when I do certain operations in my app, so I'm pretty sure is not from another process.

It's true, I don't see the state of the java process as being `D`. Is `delayacct_blkio_ticks` only reporting time in this state?

Comment: Can you please show what you're seeing w/ `top`?

Comment: You might be interested by [iosnoop](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-16/iosnoop-for-linux.html).

Comment: I've updated the description with the top output.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to read programmatically that stat field and I was wondering why it's 0. I suspect that might have to so something with the process state, maybe only D state waits are counted?

Comment: You may  be interested in https://www.monperrus.net/martin/precisely+measuring+the+maximal+disk+latency