# Where to find iowait stat for a single process (as a file)

Tags: linux, io, proc

I am writing a script and I need to find a file in which statistics for a single process/pid/service's iowait are stored. Is there any such file at all on **Debian-based** distributions?

Nor `/proc/<pid>/stat`, neither `/proc/<pid>/io` have any stat for **iowait**, according to the man pages. I am aware I can parse the output of other tools like **iotop**, **sar**, and etc., however, parsing stdout of external commands is a performance issue which I have to avoid.

**Note**: I am aware of `/proc/stat` and the meaning of its contents. I need the *iowait* stat for a **single process**, not for the whole CPU or a core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you can obtain `iowait` per process from `/proc/[pid]/stat`, since from corresponding block of [PROC(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) we read:

```
(42) delayacct_blkio_ticks  %llu  (since Linux 2.6.18)
     Aggregated block I/O delays, measured in clock ticks (centiseconds).
```

I have no idea what the `delayacct_blkio_ticks` means practically. Anyway, the only `man proc` will be useful to you.

There is related question, check it: [Measuring block I/O delays using proc FS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456575/measuring-block-i-o-delays-using-proc-fs)

Additionally, pay your attention to notes for `/proc/stat` in the per CPU `iowait` block:

> 1. The  CPU  will  not wait for I/O to complete; iowait is the time that a task is waiting for I/O to complete.  When a CPU goes into idle
>      state for outstanding task I/O, another task will be scheduled on this
>      CPU.
> 2. On a multi-core CPU, the task waiting for I/O to complete is not running on any CPU, so the iowait of each CPU is difficult to
>      calculate.
> 3. The value in this field may decrease in certain conditions.

You can get `iowait` data per CPU from `/proc/stat`. On my Ubuntu 18.04 in the `/proc/stat` there is such the part:

```
cpu  2752162 16054 941158 49212025 789607 0 217089 0 0 0
cpu0 1397207 7767 500620 24623046 407078 0 70574 0 0 0
cpu1 1354955 8286 440538 24588978 382529 0 146515 0 0 0
```

The fifth column besides `cpu`s column is `iowait` value **in my particular case**. The number of columns and its meaning can be various depending on your kernel in use.

To get every column exact meaning you have to look at your documentation. In Ubuntu install `linux-doc` package first:

```
sudo apt install linux-doc
```

and look at `man proc`:

```
man proc
```

There is part with exact `/proc/stat` explanation for every column.

Read additionally [How to read the Linux /proc/stat file](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk65143) to know how to calculate values.

In CentOS it's necessary to install `kernel-doc` package:

```
yum install kernel-doc
```

then read the file:

```
/usr/share/doc/kernel-doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt
```

Comment: I am aware of what `/proc/stat` is and of its contents. However, I've explicitly said that I need iowait for a **single** process, not for a core. Thank you for the detailed answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Fanatique I have edited my answer, please, check it.

Comment: I'll have to do with that. Anyways, great! Thank you, I have no idea how I've missed that in the man pages.. Guess I haven't been reading enough thoroughly.

Comment: @Fanatique You're welcome!